# Get marker added by google map drawing

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using google map drawing library to draw shapes like polygon, rectangle and etc. I want to know how can I get shape object after drawing is done on map.

Any advice will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use event listeners for any shapes being added.  Either using a specific listener for certain types, or the generic `overlay` complete for all shape types.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'circlecomplete', function(circle) {
  var radius = circle.getRadius();
});

google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(event) {
  if (event.type == 'circle') {
    var radius = event.overlay.getRadius();
  }
});
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/drawinglayer#drawing_events

You could probably do something like:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: 'hello'
});


google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'markercomplete', function(marker) {
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But the goal is to keep an instance of that shape, For example when a marker placed inside the map I want to bind click listener so user can click on that marker to view its details inside infoWindow, another example is to remove the marker later.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I want, I thought that param (circle or event) passed to the callback method is just an event.

Comment: Only on the overlaycomplete event. On the shape-specific one, it's the shape object itself.